# Segmentation fault error in C. Code run's on friend's computer but not mine

Tags: c

I'm attempting to run some code for a project that works fine on my friend's computer, but when I attempt to run it I get a segmentation fault error.

This is the main file that was provided for us:

**EMPLOYEE_LIST.C**

```
#include "libel.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    const char *filename = "directory.txt";
    char *csv_prefix = "csv_list";
    char find_name[25];
    pi person;
    el emp_list;
    emp_list.num_people = 0;
    load_el(&emp_list, filename);
    printf("%d employees loaded.\n", emp_list.num_people);
    char cont = 'x', // initialize continue to something other than 'Y' or 'N'
        tmp;         //
    int state = -1, correct_search_val;
    char srch_critera[25] = "init";
    while (state != 4) {
        while (state < 1 || state > 4) {
            printf("1:\tAdd employee and salary\n");
            printf("2:\tSearch directory by first name\n");
            printf("3:\tGenerate CSV\n");
            printf("4:\tSave and exit program\n");
            printf("Enter an option (1-4): ");
            scanf("%d", &state);
            if (state < 1 || state > 4) {
                printf("\nError: number not in range\n\n");
            }
        }

        switch (state) {
        // add employee and salary
        case 1:
            // add one person
            printf("Enter a first name: ");
            scanf("%s", person.first);
            printf("Enter %s's last name: ", person.first);
            scanf("%s", person.last);
            printf("Enter %s's occupation: ", person.first);
            scanf("%s", person.position);
            printf("Enter %s's Salary: ", person.first);
            scanf("%lf", &person.salary);
            scanf("%c", &tmp);
            printf("Employee added.\n");
            add_person(&emp_list, person);
            // determine to add more people to the employee list
            while (cont != 'N' && emp_list.num_people < MAXPPL) {
                cont = 'x';
                while (cont != 'Y' && cont != 'N') {
                    printf("Would you like to enter another name (Y/N): ");
                    scanf("%c", &cont);
                    if (cont != 'Y' && cont != 'N') {
                        printf(
                            "Error: User entered '%c'. Must enter either 'Y' "
                            "or 'N'\n",
                            cont);
                    }
                    scanf("%c", &tmp);
                }
                if (cont != 'N') {
                    printf("Enter a first name: ");
                    scanf("%s", person.first);
                    printf("Enter %s's last name: ", person.first);
                    scanf("%s", person.last);
                    printf("Enter %s's occupation: ", person.first);
                    scanf("%s", person.position);
                    printf("Enter %s's Salary: ", person.first);
                    scanf("%lf", &person.salary);
                    scanf("%c", &tmp);
                    printf("Employee added.\n");
                    add_person(&emp_list, person);
                }
            }
            printf("\nReturning to main menu...\n\n");
            state = -1;
            break;

        // search directory by first name
        case 2:

            cont = 'x'; // reset continue to neither 'Y' nor 'N'
            while (cont != 'N') {
                cont = 'x';
                printf("Enter a person's name to search for: ");
                scanf("%s", find_name);
                scanf("%c", &tmp);
                search_el(emp_list, find_name);
                while (cont != 'Y' && cont != 'N') {
                    printf("\nContinue (Y/N)? ");

                    scanf("%c", &cont);
                    fflush(stdout); //, &tmp);
                    scanf("%c", &tmp);
                    if (cont != 'Y' && cont != 'N') {
                        printf(
                            "Error: User entered '%c'. Must enter either 'Y' "
                            "or 'N'.\n",
                            cont);
                    }
                }
            }
            printf("\nReturning to main menu...\n\n");
            state = -1;
            break;

        // generate CSV file
        case 3:
            correct_search_val = -1;
            while (correct_search_val != 0) {
                printf("Generate CSV based on? (\"Salary\", \"Position\"): ");
                scanf("%s", srch_critera);
                if (!strcmp(srch_critera, "Salary")) {
                    printf("Generating CSV based on salary...\n");
                    gen_csv_sal(&emp_list);
                    correct_search_val = 0;
                } else if (!strcmp(srch_critera, "Position")) {
                    printf("Generating CSV based on position...\n");
                    gen_csv_pos(&emp_list);
                    correct_search_val = 0;
                } else
                    printf("Options are: \"Salary\", \"Position\"\n");
            }
            printf("Returning to main menu...\n\n");
            state = -1;

        case 4:
            break;
        } // end switch
    }    // end while

    // save the employee list
    save_el(&emp_list, filename);
    printf("%d employees saved.\n", emp_list.num_people);
    return 0;
} // end main
```

And these are the files we had to create to add functionality to the above code:

**LIBEL.C**

```
#include "libel.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// ADD FUNCTION DEFINITIONS FOR LOAD_EL, SAVE_EL, ADD_PERSON, AND SERACH_EL HERE
void load_el(el *emp_list, const char *filename) {
    FILE *ifp;
    ifp = fopen(filename, "r");
    fscanf(ifp, "%d", &emp_list->num_people);

    for (int i = 0; i < emp_list->num_people; i++) {
        fscanf(
            ifp,
            "%s %s %s %lf",
            emp_list->people[i].first,
            emp_list->people[i].last,
            emp_list->people[i].position,
            &emp_list->people[i].salary);
    }
    fclose(ifp);
    return;
}

void add_person(el *emp_list, pi person) {
    emp_list->people[emp_list->num_people] = person;
    emp_list->num_people++;
    return;
}

void search_el(el emp_list, char find_name[]) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < emp_list.num_people; i++) {
        if (strcmp(emp_list.people[i].first, find_name) == 0) {
            printf(
                "\nName: %s %s\nPosition: %s\nSalary: %lf\n",
                emp_list.people[i].first,
                emp_list.people[i].last,
                emp_list.people[i].position,
                emp_list.people[i].salary);
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == 0) {
        printf("No entries with that name.\n");
    }

    return;
}
```

**LIBEL.H**

```
#ifndef _LIBCL_H_
#define _LIBCL_H_
#define MAXPPL 500
#define MAXLEN 25


struct personal_info {
    char first[MAXLEN];
    char last[MAXLEN];
    char position[MAXLEN];
    double salary;
};

typedef struct personal_info pi;


struct employee_list {
    pi people[MAXPPL];
    int num_people;
};

typedef struct employee_list el;


//ADD PROTOTYPES HERE
void load_el(el * emp_list, const char * filename);
void add_person(el * emp_list, pi person);
void search_el(el emp_list, char find_name[ ]);
void save_el(el * emp_list, const char * filename);

void gen_csv_sal(el * emp_list);
void gen_csv_pos(el * emp_list);
char * gen_file_name(char * filename, int filename_size, char * suffix, int suffix_size);
#endif
```

I ran my code through a debugger and I got the following error:

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__isoc99_fscanf (stream=0x0, format=0x401fa2 "%d") at isoc99_fscanf.c:30
30      isoc99_fscanf.c: No such file or directory.

I've never used a debugger before and I have no idea exactly what this means so any clarification would be nice.

Everything should be working fine as my friend is able to compile and run with no issues. I'm not getting any sort of error other than "segmentation fault" when I attempt to run the code in the terminal with "./a.out" after compiling with "gcc employee_list.c libel.c" so I'm not sure what exactly the problem is. I'm using VMware workstation with a virtual mint Linux system using the default terminal. We are both using the same setup and compiling in the same way as listed above.

I'm a complete beginner with programming so any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check the return value from `fopen()`

Comment: *run's on friend's computer but not mine* that's classical undefined behaviour. Please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the format of the file "directory.txt" is not exactly the same between you both.

It looks like the input of the fscanf is 0 (NULL):

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   __isoc99_fscanf (**stream=0x0**, format=0x401fa2 "%d") at isoc99_fscanf.c:30
>   30 isoc99_fscanf.c: No such file or directory.

Also, this is never safe:

```
ifp = fopen(filename, "r");
fscanf(ifp, "%d", &emp_list->num_people);
```

Try something like:

```
void load_el(el *emp_list, const char *filename) {
  FILE *ifp;
  ifp = fopen(filename, "r");
  if(0 == ifp) {
    printf("File not found!\n");
    return;
  }
  fscanf(ifp, "%d", &emp_list->num_people);
```

I hope it helps!